# How can I replicate the pixel background in this design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, barcodes

[image]

How can I replicate the above design with Photoshop? I am having difficulty with the pixel background inside the logo.

Comment: It's really just a QR code and then "filler" on the rest of the image in the shape of batman. This is most likely an Illustrator project.

Comment: I am quite sure I have seen this exact question around here before...

Comment: Yeah,it was also me but i forgot that i asked it some time ago and i asked it again 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with three layers:

- Pattern: fill grey 50%
- Logo: the vector shape
- Background

Group the *Logo* and the *Pattern* layers holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and clicking between them at the **Layers Panel**

### Pattern Layer

- **Menu Filter** > **Noise** > **Add Noise**
- **Menu Filter** > **Pixelate** > **Mosaic**
- **Menu Image** > **Adjustments** > **Threshold**

[image]

[image]

If its necessary to simulate the QR Code, add this shape alternatively:

[image: Code]

Comment: You guys are so kind and patient. Here is my +1.

Answer (score 1):

Scan it at 600dpi or higher or simply import image into photoshop or Open in photoshop > Create copy > make new layer above layers (so your original and it's copy are the bottom 2 layers)
Select all the black in copied image using a high tolerance  while image is zoomed > Copy selection  > Paste into new layer > Repeat for white  >  Group black and white layers > merge two layers > Hide original layer > save as a .psd file

> Save as a "flattened" .PDF

Notes: original image must be high resolution ( at least 300dpi ) or an .eps file or .ai file

Use CMYK for print
Use RGB for web

Comment: You guys are so kind and patient. Here is my +1.